# wkhtmltopdf image as ObjectType

Tags: php, image, pdf, http-headers, wkhtmltopdf

i searched but couldn't find a similar post, so my apologies if i missed it.

i am using WKHTMLTOPDF from the command line in my PHP script, and it works wonderfully, but am having one slight issue.

background on my project: generate fake medical forms into html pages, and convert the html page into a pdf. the html is a simple table based off of a simple medical form (like one you would fill out at the doctors office). the html page is all text within a table with no images.

my html page successfully outputs to a pdf file, but when i check the header information:

```
    obj
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 2 0 R
    /Outlines 9 0 R
    /PageMode /UseOutlines
    /Dests <<
    /__WKANCHOR_2 8 0 R

endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Contents 12 0 R
/Resources 14 0 R
/Annots 15 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
>>
endobj
```

what i really need, is for my HTML to be stored as an image inside the PDF, so that the header comes back as:

```
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Name /Im0
/Filter [ /DCTDecode ]
/Width 1275
/Height 467
/ColorSpace 10 0 R
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Length 9 0 R
```

although my HTML is all text, is it possible, with WKHTMLTOPDF (or any other library), to store my HTML page as an image within the PDF? the PDF needs to specifically work this way because our software pulls the image out of the PDF to show as a thumbnail.

at this point i have written a small code snippet to convert my HTML to a JPEG and then into a PDF, but am having an entirely separate issue with that process.

any help is greatly appreciated. i'm entirely stuck at this point and am begging to hopefully have a fix for this. i have already read through the WKHTMLTOPDF documentation, but did not come across any viable information.

Comment: HTML-to-PDF converters generally are expected to **not** create a bitmap image of the html before PDF creation because that looses quite a lot of information and quality. Thus, I'm afraid, you'll have to use that other route, create a bitmap from the html separately and then create a PDF containing only that bitmap.

Comment: @mkl thanks for your input. that's what i was afraid of, but entirely understand why that is the case. going the other route is only an issue because i lose the 8.5 x 11 letter size, and need to develop a way to resize the jpeg when converted to a PDF.

Comment: While extremely round about, another thing you can do is to use GhostScript to convert the PDF to an image (`> convert file.pdf file.jpg`) and then convert the image to PDF. Not sure whether this will work or if you have access to install GS on the server. Pretty sure that the quality of the image will be not as good as the PDFs you currently get.

Comment: Also, wkhtmltopdf has a sibling; wkhtmltoimage. The output should be very similar to eachother, buth the other one vomits images and the other vomits PDF files. So you could feed the same HTML to the siblings and they would vomit the two files for you - that is IF you can work around "our software pulls the image out of the PDF" and have it pull from an alternate file instead. If it's your homebrew software make the developer add some way of pulling the image from an alternate source :)

Comment: @Nenotlep thanks for your input. i've taken the "sibling" route, and now have my script using wkhtmltoimage to convert the html to jpeg, and then to pdf. there isn't much loss -- if any, to the output. in any case i've gotten my script to do what was needed. thanks to everyones input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilizing the sibling WKHTMLTOIMAGE and ImageMagick, i edited my script to:

```
wkhtmltoimage file.html file.jpeg
convert file.jpeg file.pdf
```

now there is an image stored within the pdf, which can be extracted out by another developers program.